# Apache HttpClient 5.1 bypass SSL Verification

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have configured CloseableHttpAsyncClient as mentioned below

```
   public CloseableHttpAsyncClient closeableHttpAsyncClient(){
        HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom();
        final PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager connManager = new PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager();
        connManager.setMaxTotal(10);
        clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connManager);

        clientBuilder.setRedirectStrategy(DefaultRedirectStrategy.INSTANCE);
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient closeableHttpAsyncClient = clientBuilder.build();
        return closeableHttpAsyncClient;
}
```

I want to bypass SSL verification. I have tried to check different configurations but didn't find the solution for the same.

Comment: What could be a good reason to ever ignore SSL verification?

Comment: Yes, we should not bypass it. But let say there is an application where URL will be added dynamically in the application ( during runtime). So if the certificate is not present in cacert SSL exception will be thrown. Is there any good way to solve such a situation or manually add is the only way to fix it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

One can set up a custom TLS context and use it with the default TLS strategy as described here:

https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/5.1.x/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples/AsyncClientCustomSSL.java

In this particular example the connection manager has been configured to trust all certificates with the CN equal to httpbin.org in addition to standard CAs. One can choose a different stratefgy or trust all certificates indiscriminately, though the latter is STONGLY discouraged.

```
final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadTrustMaterial(new TrustStrategy() {

            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(
                    final X509Certificate[] chain,
                    final String authType) throws CertificateException {
                // Trust all certs with CN equal `httpbin.org`
                final X509Certificate cert = chain[0];
                return "CN=httpbin.org".equalsIgnoreCase(cert.getSubjectDN().getName());
            }

        })
        .build();
final TlsStrategy tlsStrategy = ClientTlsStrategyBuilder.create()
        .setSslContext(sslcontext)
        .build();
final PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager cm = PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
        .setTlsStrategy(tlsStrategy)
        .build();
```